# ImportError: DLL load failed usando sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows10, pip, scikit-learn

Tengo una Laptop con Win10 y me encuentro trabajando en Python3.6, y como ambiente de desarrollo uso el PyCharm.

He instalado por medio de Pip los siguientes paquetes:

> ```
> cycler (0.10.0)
> matplotlib (2.0.2)
> nose (1.3.7)
> numpy (1.13.1)
> pandas (0.20.3)
> pip (9.0.1)
> PyMySQL (0.7.11)
> pyparsing (2.2.0)
> python-dateutil (2.6.1)
> pytz (2017.2)
> scikit-learn (0.19.0)
> scipy (0.19.1)
> setuptools (28.8.0)
> simpy (3.0.10)
> six (1.10.0)
> virtualenv (15.1.0)
> wheel (0.30.0)
> ```

pero al ejecutar algún código con la librería sklearn, me muestra un error como el que sigue:

```
    C:\Users\jvilchez\Downloads>python -c "import sklearn; sklearn.test()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jvilchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\jvilchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\jvilchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "C:\Users\jvilchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\jvilchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 144, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\jvilchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "C:\Users\jvilchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "C:\Users\jvilchez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
```

Lo he reinstalado, he buscado información por Internet de como solucionarlo pero nada; lo que estoy tratando de hacer es usar esta librería para problemas de ML.

Comment: juan, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo que puedas poner el texto del error en vez de una imagen. Eso ayudara a que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede asegurar al 100% pero ese error es típico cuando no se tiene la versión de [NumPy con  MKL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-mkl) (Intel® **M**ath **K**ernel **L**ibrary) incluido.

Viendo tu versión de NumPy vemos que no incluye MKL, tienes:

> numpy (1.13.1)

Y debería mostrar algo como:

> numpy (1.13.1+mkl)

Para ahorrarte problemas de compilación puedes descargarte el binario correspondiente de la página de Christoph Gohlke de la Universidad de Californa que recopila una gran cantidad de binarios precompilados de la gran mayoría de bibliotecas de ámbito científico de Python:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Los pasos a seguir serian:

1. Si tienes un sistema de 64 bits con Python de 64 bits instalado debes descargarte `numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`. En caso contrario elige el archivo adecuado a tu sistema.
2. Una ves descargado, te vas a la carpeta de descarga con el Explorador de Archivos y en la barra de direcciones ingresas `cmd`. Esto te abre la terminal en ese directorio de trabajo. También puedes usar simplemente `cd` o pasar la ruta completa del archivo a `pip` después.
3. Vamos a reinstalar NumPy usando el .whl descargado. Ingresa en la terminal:

   ```
    py -3.6 -m pip install numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl --upgrade --force-reinstall
   ```

   Sustituye `numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` por el nombre de tu archivo descargado de ser necesario.

Si se instala sin errores, prueba de nuevo tu script a ver si se ha solucionado el problema.

Comment: Gracias, se ejecuto con éxito la prueba sin error.

Comment: Gracias, lo tendré en cuenta la próxima vez.